# How to disambiguate the meaning of "ricaricare" when talking about mobile phones?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

It seems to me that in Italian the word for "carrying out a mobile phone top-up" (UK) or "carrying out a mobile phone refill" (US), i.e., adding credit to a mobile phone's network operator account, is the same as the word for "recharging a mobile phone", i.e., connecting a mobile phone to a source of electricity to make sure the battery has enough charge:

- `ricaricare`

So, what's the best way to construct a sentence in Italian so as to make it clear whether "ricaricare" means topping up / refilling or recharging?

Comment: You can just say "ricaricare il credito"/"comprare credito" (both of which make me shudder, but people say that) or "ricaricare la batteria" respectively.

Comment: I believe almost in any ambiguous sentence we explicitly mention the battery if we want to mean recharge. At least, if someone told me *devo ricaricare il cellulare* I'd assume he means to buy more credit, while I'd expect him to say *devo ricaricare **la batteria** del cellulare* to mean recharging. But that's me and how they are used in my region, not sure if this holds in all Italy.

Comment: To my ears *ricaricare il cellulare* means charging the battery.

Comment: Good question. It's something I've never thought about because, generally, with `ricarico il telefono` you mean topping-up it and either by specifying  `la batteria` or by using `caricare` to mean a physical recharge.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps `ricaricare` can be used with the meaning of `topping-up`, whereas `caricare` can be used with the meaning of `charging the battery`.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to disambiguate without using additional context, I suggest

> caricare

for charging the battery and

> fare una ricarica

for topping up the credit. I am pretty sure that these are not prone to confusion in any part of Italy.

Comment: True. I think the second case sounds even better if stated as `effettuare una ricarica`.

Comment: It is a bit more formal. In everyday context you would say "fare".

Comment: I don't really agree with this. I would say that this is just ambiguous in the way people speak. You have to specify *what* you want to recharge.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the word is the same. I never really thought of the possible confusion though. 
I would use different expressions, or in most cases people would understand it from the context:

> Sono senza soldi sul cell, devo ricaricare

*I'm out of money (credit) on my cellphone, I have to top-up*

> Devo comprare una ricarica del cellulare

"I have to buy phone credit/top-up"

VS.

> Ho la batteria scarica, devo ricaricare il cellulare

*My battery is (almost) dead, I have to recharge my phone*

Answer (score 1):

- (ri)caricare la batteria (del telefonino). (to charge the battery (of the mobile phone))
- effettuare una ricarica (to top-up one's phone).

Thank you for your helpful replies.

Comment: Yes, but nobody would actually say “effettuare una ricarica”: this is something you'd only find, say, in the instructions for how to do it.